# FLOSS Dataflow generator for SQL

Tags: open-source, charts, sql, dataflow

I'm looking for a (FLOSS) dataflow chart generator which is capable to build up flow based on a list of SQL queries thrown against the database. So something like

```
SELECT * INTO myTable FROM oldTable;
```

should end up as something like 
`oldTable` --> `myTable` (of course with some graphical eyecandy ;) )

Comment: "Oldtable" -> "Mytable" makes sense with "star".   How fine grain do you want this?  Do you want know merely   X -affects-> Y,  or do you want to know   X -howaffects->Y?

Comment: a would be already great b would be perfect with some candy on top